# How to detect cause of this crash from Crashlytics?

Tags: java, android, string, exception, crashlytics-android

Suddenly my app started to crash enormously. I checked Crashlytics report but it doesn't tell me much. This is what it says, hopefully someone could give me a hint if had same/similar problem..

[image: Crashlytics report]

Comment: Paste the raw crash log. May be then people could help.

Comment: StringIndexOutOfBoundsException -- if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

Comment: You are trying to get a string from index 0 to -2, which is not possible. Check your logic and fix the end index.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 but how can I detect where it's happening? ..This ServiceInfoImpl class is generic and it can't be modified

Comment: I think @user8789149  knows what is `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` the problem is that were should the exception be fixed. Such exceptions with ambiguous stack traces happen very often, unfortunately :(

Comment: Yep :/  I have like 500 crashes on only 2 users..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be related to a known jmDNS bug that was supposedly fixed a long time ago<sup>1</sup>:

- https://sourceforge.net/p/jmdns/bugs/101/
- https://sourceforge.net/p/jmdns/mailman/jmdns-discuss/thread/4EA5B242.4070003@gmail.com/

Apparently, the problem is triggered by lookup of malformed DNS names: see last email in discussion thread.

I suggest that you add some diagnostics to your app to find out what name your code is attempting to lookup.

---

<sup>1 - I have my doubts that it was actually fixed ... based on the discussion thread.</sup>

Comment: Great, tnx! .. At least I know where to look for now